# Problems installing own app on Android Smartwatch

Tags: android, wear-os

First off my devices and software:
Smartphone: Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2)
Smartwatch: Motorola Moto 360 First generation (Android 6.0.1)
Development software: Android Studio 3.1.3
Operating system: Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit.

I was able to install my own app on my Smartphone.
The only thing I did was generating an APK file, copying it to the sd card of my phone
and installing it.
(The phone was connected via USB.)
I had to change the minimum sdk to 19 (target sdk = 27).

Now I tried to do the same with my 2nd app (which is just for the watch).
Unfortunately, I haven't had success yet.
When I copy the app to my phone, I can't start it -> Parsing error.
The problem is that I can't set the minimum sdk to lower than 23.

After reading a lot on the Internet I tried out a completely different way.
For both devices I enabled the dev mode and turned on USB debugging + Bluetooth USB debugging.
Additionally I went to Windows 7 system settings and added the path of Android.
Right now, I'm able to type in commands like "adb devices" in cmd.exe

Sadly, I can't connect to my watch.
In on YT tutorial they say, "adb forward tcp:6666 localabstract:/adb-hub".
Whenever I try this, I receive the error message: "error: unknown host service"
Also another hint didn't work:
adb forward -remove tcp:4444
adb forward tcp:4444localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444

As you can see, both ways don't lead to success.

Do you have any suggestion how I can install my app on my watch?
I don't prefer any specific way, the main point is that it works.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. If you need further details, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Do you have the Android Wear phone app installed on the Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app

Comment: Yes, my phone and my watch are connected together, using the Wear OS. They communicate perfectly each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with another phone? Have you installed the needed dependencies for target sdks below 23? It seems you need API21 for android wear.
See example here https://www.telerik.com/blogs/build-your-first-google-wear-app